# GTalk API in asp,net

Tags: .net, api, google-talk, messenger

I would like to build an asp.net web application that uses GTalk / Yahoo messenger api that sends a predefined message to a server and receive back confirmation message from the other end. I want to implement it without using any gui(messenger/gtalk ), but want to implement it through api calls only.

Your help is much appreciated